# What am I doing wrong with hosting a hidden service?

Tags: web-hosting

Here is what I did:

1. Install TOR and Savant
2. Changed the DNS entry to localhost and the port to 80
3. Modified torrc. Here is the text:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

Bridge obfs4 [stuff here]
Bridge obfs4 [stuff here]
Bridge obfs4 [stuff here]
DataDirectory C:\Program Files\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Program Files\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Program Files\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceDir C:\Program Files\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\Website
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
UseBridges 1
```

The only thing I added to the Tor\Website directory is index.html

4. Opened Tor
5. Went to the URL that was generated

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should not use your hidden service directory as the root directory of your web server, so your index.html should not go in this directory. Also are you sure you want to run a hidden service through your browser? Can you also share what your error is?

Comment: But what's the problem?